# unable to run test using tox.ini file

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, tox

I am using `unittest` as the library for the unit testing purposes. I was trying to run the below test via `tox.ini` file.

```
from services.snowflake_api import SnowflakeApi
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch


class SnowflakeDbTest(TestCase):

    @patch('services.SnowflakeAPI.snowflake.connector')  # Decorator where  database object is configured...
    def test_get_database_connection(self, mock_connection):
        mock_connection.connect.return_value = "dbconnection"  # Setting up the mock value that would be returned after calling db get connection method...
        self.assertEqual("dbconnection",
                         SnowflakeApi.get_database_connection("user", "password", "account", "warehouse",
                                                              database=None, schema=None))
```

**`tox.ini:`**

```
[tox]
envlist = py310

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest
```

`Error`:

```
/Users/abc/IdeaProjects/python_project/venv/bin/python /Users/abc/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_tox_runner.py 
Testing started at 8:24 pm ...
GLOB sdist-make: /Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module/setup.py
py310 inst-nodeps: /Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module/.tox/.tmp/package/1/dm-snowflake-1.0.0.zip
WARNING: Discarding $PYTHONPATH from environment, to override specify PYTHONPATH in 'passenv' in your configuration.
py310 installed: asn1crypto==1.4.0,attrs==22.1.0,certifi==2021.10.8,cffi==1.15.0,charset-normalizer==2.0.9,cryptography==35.0.0,distlib==0.3.4,dm-snowflake==1.0.0,filelock==3.4.2,idna==3.3,iniconfig==1.1.1,oscrypto==1.2.1,packaging==21.3,platformdirs==2.4.1,pluggy==1.0.0,py==1.11.0,pycparser==2.21,pycryptodomex==3.15.0,PyJWT==2.3.0,pyOpenSSL==21.0.0,pyparsing==3.0.6,pytest==6.2.5,pytz==2021.3,requests==2.27.1,six==1.16.0,snowflake-connector-python==2.7.2,toml==0.10.2,tox==3.25.1,urllib3==1.26.7,virtualenv==20.13.2
py310 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2295913608'
py310 run-test: commands[0] | /Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module/.tox/py310/bin/python '/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py' --offset 1 --
Launching pytest with arguments --no-header --no-summary -q in /Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module

============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.01s =============================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module/.tox/py310/bin/python '/Users/abc/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py' --offset 1 -- (exited with code 5)

commands failed
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   py310: commands failed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am also sharing my project structure below:

[image]

`Error`:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... 
tests/snowflake/test_example_01.py:None (tests/snowflake/test_example_01.py)
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/abc/IdeaProjects/project/abc/module/tests/snowflake/test_example_01.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
.tox/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:608: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
.tox/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:533: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688: in _load_unlocked
    ???
.tox/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:168: in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tests/snowflake/test_example_01.py:3: in <module>
    from mock import patch
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `tox` issue, but rather a `pytest` one.

Let's have a look at the error message:

```
collecting ... collected 0 items
```

`pytest` has not collected a single test, returns a non-zero exit code, and so `tox` also fails.

Having a look at [pytest's test discovery convention](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) it is clear, that `pytest` only collects tests from classes beginning with `Test`, not ending with `Test`.

You need to either adapt `pytest`s default behavior for test discovery, or configure it differently, see https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: I have shared the project structure screenshot. Even with this `tests` structure it is giving the attached error. What's wrong in this?

Comment: Also, I am using unittest as the library in my test development and not pytest.

Comment: You do use pytest. See your tox.ini

Comment: On StackOverflow usually it is a good idea to create separate questions for separate problems. Your second problem is a incorrect import statement. Instead of `from mock import patch` you need to write `from unittest.mock import patch`. If you encounter even more issues, please create a new question. thank you!